# Event handling with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I just started learning WPF and C#.

I'm trying to listen to global events on my WPF application. It has to run during the entire time the program is running. On a console application, I would run the logic in the Main() function. However, Main() is generated during compile time in a WPF application.

Where do I put the event handlers in a WPF application?

Comment: You do not listen to events in WPF. You use MVVM.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about, you don't listen to events? You listen to events all over the place. Data binding only gets you so far; for example sometimes you need a global mouse or keyboard hook, you can only do that with an event. Why would they provide routed events if you didn't need to listen to events? What event do you need to listen to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by Global events in this context, but what I usually do is this :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

This is the MainWindow.xaml.cs class that is generated in every WPF template in Visual Studio.